# Upper and Lower camel case

Tags: regex, camelcasing

I am trying to come up with a regex for both Upper and lower Camel case.

Here is what I tried

```
(([A-Z][a-z0-9]*){2,}|([a-z][A-Z0-9]*){2,})
```

Trying to match Upper camel case with this - ([A-Z][a-z0-9]*){2,} but it is matching other combinations as well.
Similar is the case with the second part - ([a-z][A-Z0-9]*){2,})

Comment: What is the meaning of the {2,}? that single letter variables are prohibited?

Comment: That is to make sure ([A-Z][a-z0-9]*) or ([a-z][A-Z0-9]*) occurs at least twice. @SWeko

Comment: can you give some examples please of the text you are testing with?

Comment: Upper camel case - "CamelCase1" 
Lower camel case - "camelCase2"
@JackDev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would match upper and lower camel case phrases containing at least one upper case in the word.

**Upper Camel Case**

```
[A-Z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z0-9][a-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

example:HelloWorld, AQuickBrownFox

**Lower Camel Case**

```
[a-z]+[A-Z0-9][a-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

example: helloWorld, aQuickBrownFox

Comment: So, in `UpperCamelCase`, only `UpperCamel` will be matched. Is that intentional? Then, wouldn't you want to use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in order not to match (a substring of) `thisIsNotUpperCamelCase` with your first regex? Also, it should be `[A-Z]`, not `[A-Z0-9]`. Finally, (and the OP didn't mention this) what about non-ASCII variable names? Many languages allow Unicode characters for variable names.

Comment: But the lowerCamelCase RegEx also matches strings like `A` or even `ABC`! I think it should rather be `[a-z]+[A-Z0-9][a-z0-9]*`. Note the `+` instead of the `*`.

Comment: also updated my regular expression to handle more complicated matches.

Answer (score 2):

### Lower Camel Case - no digits allowed

```
    ^[a-z][a-z]*(([A-Z][a-z]+)*[A-Z]?|([a-z]+[A-Z])*|[A-Z])$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/4h7A1I

### Lower Camel Case - digits allowed

```
    ^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*[A-Z]?|([a-z0-9]+[A-Z])*|[A-Z])$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/8nQras

### Lower Camel Case - digits allowed - Upto 3 upper case letters

To match more than one upper case letter (eg. `deviceID`, `serialNO`, `awsVPC`, `deviceSN`) it gets slightly more involved:

```
 
    ^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(([A-Z]{1,3}[a-z0-9]+)*[A-Z]{0,3}|([a-z0-9]+[A-Z]{1,3})*|[A-Z]{1,3})$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/C2eHyc

### Pascal Case - no digits allowed

```
    ^[A-Z](([a-z]+[A-Z]?)*)$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/sF2jRZ

### Pascal Case - digits allowed

```
    ^[A-Z](([a-z0-9]+[A-Z]?)*)$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/csrkQw

### Pascal Case - digits allowed - Upto 3 upper case letters

To match more than one upper case letter (eg. `DeviceID`, `SerialNo`, `AwsVPC`, `IOStream`, `StreamIO`, `DeviceSN`) it gets slightly more involved:

```
    ^[A-Z](([A-Z]{1,2}[a-z0-9]+)+([A-Z]{1,3}[a-z0-9]+)*[A-Z]{0,3}|([a-z0-9]+[A-Z]{0,3})*|[A-Z]{1,2})$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/TLTXbK

For more details on camel case and pascal case check out this [repo](https://github.com/roubles/casing).

Answer (score 0):

For lowerCamelCase you need:

1. A lowerCaseLetter
2. at least one (lowerCaseLetter or UpperCaseLetter or numb3r)

So an approriate regex would be

```
[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Similarly for UpperCamelCase, you'll have `[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+`, and if you group those, you get

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Edit: If you strictly require that for a word to be a camel case word, it heeds to have a "hump", where a hump is an uppercase letter or a number, you need:

1. An upper or a lower case letter, followed by
2. Other lower case letters (maybe none), followed by
3. A hump, followed by
4. Other lower case letters (maybe none),
5. Maybe followed by another hump(s)

Then your regex is:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-z]*([A-Z0-9]+[a-z]*)+
```

Comment: But this will match "aa" as well which is not a camel case, right?

Comment: it is if it's a single word. lowerCamelCase for a variable called lower is `lower`. Try to have a rigorous definition for lower/UpperCamelCase. Then the regex will write itself.

Comment: I want to match texts like
Upper camel case - "CamelCase1" and "camelCase2" for lower camel case!

Comment: Those are indeed matched, both by my regex, and the regex you gave. (http://refiddle.com/gvg)

Comment: Shouldn't this regex only match the Camel case and not other words like "aa" etc? But in this case, it is matching words apart from camel cases as well. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, sorry. So a word is only camel case when there is an actual "hump", so "lower" and "Upper" are not matches. Is a number considered a hump, i.e. should "lower8", "lower8Upper", "lower8lower", or "lower8UPPER" be matched?

Comment: I think there can be.